# Drupal 9.5 CMS comparator (<, >) script code unable to load in custom block

Tags: drupal

[image]

this one i tried

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
let x = 5;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x < 8);
</script>
```

its converting like below one

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
let x = 5;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x &lt; 8);
</script>
```